google::EnableLogCleaner() function of GLOG doesn't work
I'm using GLOG v0.6.0, where I want to use google::EnableLogCleaner() to delete any logs older than 1 day is present in the logs folder. But google::EnableLogCleaner()  seems to be not working for me.
Repo ref : https://github.com/google/glog/tree/v0.6.0
Minimal error reproducing code :
void main(int argc, char** argv) {
  
    std::string filePath = GetFilePath("GLOG_TEST");
    FLAGS_alsologtostderr = true;
    FLAGS_colorlogtostderr = true;
    
    google::InitGoogleLogging("");
    google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_INFO, (filePath + "_INFO").c_str());
    google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_WARNING, (filePath + "_WARN").c_str());
    google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_ERROR, (filePath + "_ERROR").c_str());

    google::EnableLogCleaner(1); // logs older than 1 days should have gotten deleted automatically.

    LOG_IF(INFO, 1) << " {INFO} My first log statement!";
    LOG_IF(WARNING, 1) << " {WARNING} My first log statement!";
    LOG_IF(ERROR, 1) << " {ERROR} My first log statement!";
    return;
}

To test EnableLogCleaner() I change my system's date to 3 days in future but it doesn't delete any older log files.
Things I tried :

I have tried running program in admin mode if there is any permission related issue but that is not the case.
Tried explicitly calling google::FlushLogFiles(google::GLOG_ERROR) but that didn't work too.

